# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: "text_file"

Tags: python

Im getting this error :

```
  File "C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/project/Project.py", line 207, in record_attendance
    with open("SOFT_6017.txt", "w") as module_1:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'SOFT_6017.txt'
```

I've searched all over the web and wasn't able to find an answer to my solution. i asked a phew people and they didn't know what to do with it. So they suggested to me to write a question here.

Content of SOFT_6017:

```
Mary Martin,10,0,0
Alan Wilson,0,9,1
Alan Lowe,5,6,0
```

Where im trying to add that details:

```
   with open("SOFT_6017.txt", "w") as module_1:
        soft_6017_1 = module_1.readline().split(',')
        soft_6017_2 = module_1.readline().split(',')
        soft_6017_3 = module_1.readline().split(',')

        name_1_1 = soft_6017_1[0]
        attended_1_1 = int(soft_6017_1[1])
        missed_1_1 = int(soft_6017_1[2])
        excused_1_1 = int(soft_6017_1[3])

        name_2_1 = soft_6017_2[0]
        attended_2_1 = int(soft_6017_2[1])
        missed_2_1 = int(soft_6017_2[2])
        excused_2_1 = int(soft_6017_2[3])

        name_3_1 = soft_6017_3[0]
        attended_3_1 = int(soft_6017_3[1])
        missed_3_1 = int(soft_6017_3[2])
        excused_3_1 = int(soft_6017_3[3])

        count_1 = len(open("SOFT_6017.txt").readlines())

        data = f"{name_1_1}, {attended_1_1}, {missed_1_1}, {excused_1_1} \n " \
               f"{name_2_1}, {attended_2_1}, {missed_2_1}, {excused_2_1} \n " \
               f"{name_3_1}, {attended_3_1}, {missed_3_1}, {excused_3_1}"

        module_1.seek(0)
        module_1.write(data)
```

Line 207 - with open("SOFT_6017.txt", "w") as module_1: this line.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to read the file which you have opened in write mode.
Change this

```
with open("SOFT_6017.txt", "w") as module_1:
```

To this

```
with open("SOFT_6017.txt", "r") as module_1:
```

And to write data to the file, remove this line:

```
module_1.write(data)
```

and open another `with` block:

```
with open("SOFT_6017.txt", "w") as mod_wr:
    mod_wr.write(data)
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: now im getting this error:
  File "C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/project/Project.py", line 234, in record_attendance
    module_1.write(data)
io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable

Comment: @MaksimsKazoha I've updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: i used it and this came up:   File "C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/project/Project.py", line 234, in record_attendance
    with open("SOFT_6017.txt", "w") as mod_wr:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'SOFT_6017.txt'

Comment: @MaksimsKazoha If you are still getting this Permission Error, then it simply means that You only have permission to read that file. You don't have permission to write content to that file. So try changing file permissions.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you can have open your archive "SOFT_6017.txt", try to close it and try again.

Comment: I reset the pc and nothing changed.